# Enqueue Style in Functions.php

Tags: functions

This doesn't work for me in `functions.php`:

```
    if( is_page_template( 'template-flat.php' ) ) {

function flatsome_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'flatsome-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/flatash/css/foundation.css', array(), '2.1', 'all');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'flatsome_scripts' );

    }
```

However, if I include the style manually in the header of `template-flat.php` like this it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/flatash/css/foundation.css" type="text/css" />
```

Why is my functions code not working?

Comment: Is your code wrapped inside a function hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`?

Comment: Are you hooking the code in functions.php in any action hook? If so, please, show us. Also, you have mentioned "header" of template-flat.php, please show us also the header of this file.

Comment: Are you calling wp_enqueue_style within a function?

Comment: WOW, all of us asking almost the same at the same time ;)

Comment: yes calling within a function, I have updated my code - but still doesnt work :(

Comment: Take a glance at the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). The code in `functions.php` executes at `after_setup_theme`, however [conditionals do not function properly until `posts_selection`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). The `wp_enqueue_scripts` action occurs after all of the above, meaning code executed here can use conditionals. Long story short, move your `if( is_page_template( 'template-flat.php' ) )` conditional _inside_ of `flatsome_scripts()`

Comment: [Your newer question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177227) is technically identical to this one - in both scenarios your code is not functioning correctly due to premature use of conditional tags. I've provided a more detailed breakdown of the issue on the other question, however I feel these two questions should be reconciled into a single, more general question.

Comment: this question has not been answered in the thread that someone specified above...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have wrapped your complete function and your action inside your conditional check. Your conditional check for your page template should be in your function.

Page templates gets set quite late, too late for your action.

Your function should look like this

```
function flatsome_scripts() 
{

    if( is_page_template( 'template-flat.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'flatsome-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/flatash/css/foundation.css', array(), '2.1', 'all');
    }

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'flatsome_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it, the same way you do it to register other scripts, put it in a function and then add then use add_action. This goes in functions.php.

```
function register_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'flatsome-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/flatash/css/foundation.css', array(), '2.1', 'all');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','register_styles');
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you place the conditional inside the function, like:

```
function flatsome_scripts() {
    if( is_page_template( 'template-flat.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'flatsome-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/flatash/css/foundation.css', array(), '2.1', 'all');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'flatsome_scripts' );
```